# Apply method to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a method to a variable to be used as following;

```
var method = ".wrap";   
jQuery('.container')+[method]+("<div>Hello World</div>");
```

Essentially what it should do is;

```
jQuery('.container').wrap("<div>Hello World</div>");
```

but it does not work, no error, the hello world div is not being added in the page.
Here is the original question http://goo.gl/MQ2tr, I thought I ask it again in simpler terms.

**update**
As long as I have a single method inside the variable it works nice with bracket notation, however I need to use something like `.parent().parent().wrap()` how can I make it work? i tried removing all the dots but i just get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'parent()parent()wrap'`

Here is how my list form looks like now

```
 <select name="lu_ban_data[method]" id="lu_ban_data" />
        <option value="append">Append</option>
        <option value="prepend">Prepend</option>
        <option value="wrap">Wrap</option>
        <option value="parent()parent()wrap">Parent</option>
</select>
```

Comment: are you trying to add a CSS class?

Comment: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write it this way:

```
var method = "wrap";   
jQuery('.container')[method]("<div>Hello World</div>");
```

You can access properties of an object in two ways. Either by *dot notation* or by *square bracket notation*

```
 obj.property
 obj['property']

 var propName = "property"
 obj[propName]
```

**EDIT**

Here the link to MDN [Member Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

A short explanation to what your code does:

```
  jQuery('.container')+[method]+("<div>Hello World</div>");
```

It is an addition of 3 element:

1. The result set of `jQuery('.container')`
2. An `Array` containing one element `[method]`
3. The `String` `"<div>Hello World</div>"`

The result of this depends on the implementation but would most likely be something like this:

```
"[object Object].wrap<div>Hello World</div>"
 +-------------+
                +---+
                     +--------------------+
```

The result looks this way because the JavaScript-Engines normally call `toString` on the elements if they can't add them in another way.

**EDIT**

Update to the edited question:

```
 element.parent().parent().wrap()
```

would e.g. equal to:

```
 element['parent']()['parent']().wrap()
```

or

```
 element['parent']().parent()['wrap']()
```

or any other combination ob *dot* or *brace* notation

You want to represent `.parent().parent().wrap()` as one string and use this as access.
But this would not work that way. The *dot notation* or *brace notation* only return the property of the given element. So `parent()` returns the `parent` of `jQuery('.container')` on this returned object you call `parant()` and on that returned object you call `wrap()`

So (assuming only your last function call would have arguments) you would need something like this:

```
function chainedFunctionCall( obj, chain, arguments) {
    var curr = obj;
    var splitChain = chain.split(".");  //split the 'call chain' passed a strings by '.' (the dot in the string has nothing to do with the dot notation)

    //iterate over the resulting array (except the last one where we need to pass the arguments to
    for( var i=0 ; i<splitChain.length-1 ; i++ ) {
        //call the function by the given name in the chain and store the result as current object
        curr = curr[splitChain[i]]();
    }

    //when we reached the last name in the chain call that function using `apply` so that we can pass the arguments we got as array to the function call, and call it in the context of the current object.
    return curr[splitChain[i]].apply(curr,arguments);
}


var obj = $(".container");
var callChain = "parent.parent.wrap";


chainedFunctionCall( obj, callChain, ["<div>your argument you pass there</div>"]);
```

Comment: It's not called "array notation"...it's "bracket notation" (and I think there's another name for it)

Comment: it's somehow working, im gona run some test as the method is being pulled from a serialized array then localized to be used in the function.

Comment: @lan you are right, i search for the real word in my brain and net :D

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos I added an explanation why your code does not result in an error. And what it does.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the pointers, I updated the question, it is working now as long as assign the variable a single method such as "wrap or append or prepend", however I need to be able to also use something like ".parent().parent().wrap" how can i do it

Comment: You can mix them. You can write `jQuery(".test").parent()['parent']().parent()`. despite that it is probably not readable it works.

Comment: No matter what combination I used in the value of the field list, it doesnt work `<option value="parent[]parent[].wrap">Parent</option>` it only works with a single method ie. `<option value="append">Append</option>` I am reading your updated answer and it seems that it can't be done?

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos added the info how it can be done but it is limited in what you can do and you really should think over if you can do it in an other way. And please try to understand the code then just using it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for everything, using the bracket notation worked, I just had to remove the dots from the form element, as for the argumentative methods I had to create two conditionals one that would see if the method is not parent then use bracket notation fetching the localized method and else if the method is parent run a code that has the parent().parent().wrap("<div>hello world</div>")